# formatting data for fixed-effect regression (paneldata) in python?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, panel-data

I have a large data set i need to conduct time-series analysis on. The data is currently in excel formated as below:

```
+----+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
| ID | Q1 09 variable X | Q2 09 variable X | Q3 09 variable X | Q4 09 variable X | Q1 10 variable X | Q2 10 variable X | Q3 10 variable X | Q4 10 variable X | Q1 09 variable Y | Q2 09 variable Y | Q3 09 variable Y | Q4 09 variable Y | Q1 10 variable Y | Q2 10 variable Y | Q3 10 variable Y | Q4 10 variable Y |
+----+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
|  1 | X                | X                | X                | X                | X                | X                | X                | X                | Y                | Y                | Y                | Y                | Y                | Y                | Y                | Y                |
|  2 | X                | X                | X                | X                | X                | X                | X                | X                | Y                | Y                | Y                | Y                | Y                | Y                | Y                | Y                |
|  3 | X                | X                | X                | X                | X                | X                | X                | X                | Y                | Y                | Y                | Y                | Y                | Y                | Y                | Y                |
|  4 | X                | X                | X                | X                | X                | X                | X                | X                | Y                | Y                | Y                | Y                | Y                | Y                | Y                | Y                |
|  5 | X                | X                | X                | X                | X                | X                | X                | X                | Y                | Y                | Y                | Y                | Y                | Y                | Y                | Y                |
|  6 | X                | X                | X                | X                | X                | X                | X                | X                | Y                | Y                | Y                | Y                | Y                | Y                | Y                | Y                |
|  7 | X                | X                | X                | X                | X                | X                | X                | X                | Y                | Y                | Y                | Y                | Y                | Y                | Y                | Y                |
|  8 | X                | X                | X                | X                | X                | X                | X                | X                | Y                | Y                | Y                | Y                | Y                | Y                | Y                | Y                |
|  9 | X                | X                | X                | X                | X                | X                | X                | X                | Y                | Y                | Y                | Y                | Y                | Y                | Y                | Y                |
+----+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
```

The above table is an example. The dataset contains data on all quarters up to Q1 2019. I need the data to look like this:

```
+----+-------+------------+------------+
| ID |   T   | Variable X | Variable Y |
+----+-------+------------+------------+
|  1 | Q1 09 | X          | Y          |
|  1 | Q2 09 | X          | Y          |
|  1 | Q3 09 | X          | Y          |
|  1 | Q4 09 | X          | Y          |
|  1 | Q1 10 | X          | Y          |
|  1 | Q2 10 | X          | Y          |
|  1 | Q3 10 | X          | Y          |
|  1 | Q4 10 | X          | Y          |
|  2 | Q1 09 | X          | Y          |
|  2 | Q2 09 | X          | Y          |
|  2 | Q3 09 | X          | Y          |
|  2 | Q4 09 | X          | Y          |
|  2 | Q1 10 | X          | Y          |
|  2 | Q2 10 | X          | Y          |
|  2 | Q3 10 | X          | Y          |
|  2 | Q4 10 | X          | Y          |
|  3 | Q1 09 | X          | Y          |
|  3 | Q2 09 | X          | Y          |
|  3 | Q3 09 | X          | Y          |
|  3 | Q4 09 | X          | Y          |
|  3 | Q1 10 | X          | Y          |
|  3 | Q2 10 | X          | Y          |
|  3 | Q3 10 | X          | Y          |
|  3 | Q4 10 | X          | Y          |
|  4 | Q1 09 | X          | Y          |
|  4 | Q2 09 | X          | Y          |
|  4 | Q3 09 | X          | Y          |
|  4 | Q4 09 | X          | Y          |
|  4 | Q1 10 | X          | Y          |
|  4 | Q2 10 | X          | Y          |
|  4 | Q3 10 | X          | Y          |
|  4 | Q4 10 | X          | Y          |
|  5 | Q1 09 | X          | Y          |
|  5 | Q2 09 | X          | Y          |
|  5 | Q3 09 | X          | Y          |
|  5 | Q4 09 | X          | Y          |
|  5 | Q1 10 | X          | Y          |
|  5 | Q2 10 | X          | Y          |
|  5 | Q3 10 | X          | Y          |
|  5 | Q4 10 | X          | Y          |
|  6 | Q1 09 | X          | Y          |
|  6 | Q2 09 | X          | Y          |
|  6 | Q3 09 | X          | Y          |
|  6 | Q4 09 | X          | Y          |
|  6 | Q1 10 | X          | Y          |
|  6 | Q2 10 | X          | Y          |
|  6 | Q3 10 | X          | Y          |
|  6 | Q4 10 | X          | Y          |
|  7 | Q1 09 | X          | Y          |
|  7 | Q2 09 | X          | Y          |
|  7 | Q3 09 | X          | Y          |
|  7 | Q4 09 | X          | Y          |
|  7 | Q1 10 | X          | Y          |
|  7 | Q2 10 | X          | Y          |
|  7 | Q3 10 | X          | Y          |
|  7 | Q4 10 | X          | Y          |
|  8 | Q1 09 | X          | Y          |
|  8 | Q2 09 | X          | Y          |
|  8 | Q3 09 | X          | Y          |
|  8 | Q4 09 | X          | Y          |
|  8 | Q1 10 | X          | Y          |
|  8 | Q2 10 | X          | Y          |
|  8 | Q3 10 | X          | Y          |
|  8 | Q4 10 | X          | Y          |
|  9 | Q1 09 | X          | Y          |
|  9 | Q2 09 | X          | Y          |
|  9 | Q3 09 | X          | Y          |
|  9 | Q4 09 | X          | Y          |
|  9 | Q1 10 | X          | Y          |
|  9 | Q2 10 | X          | Y          |
|  9 | Q3 10 | X          | Y          |
|  9 | Q4 10 | X          | Y          |
+----+-------+------------+------------+
```

The data set is very large, several thousands data points in total.

I previosuly posted regarding this issue, but I guess I did not formulate the question properly. i i tried the code below, but it left out the Y column.

```
df.columns = [
    df.columns.to_series().groupby(level=0).cumcount().map({0: 'X', 1: 'Y'}),
    df.columns
]

df.stack().rename_axis(['ID', 'T']).reset_index()
```

Comment: Sidenote: this is definitely a usecase for [`pd.wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html), just couldn't get it to work with the `stubnames` argument.

Answer (score 2):

We can split your dataframe by variables (X, Y) with [`df.filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html). Then we melt your columns to rows with [`.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html). Finally we concat the seperated data together again with [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html).

The last line is to clean up your `T` column by removing everything with format:
`variable X`

```
X = df[['ID']].join(df.filter(regex='X$')).melt(id_vars='ID', var_name='T', value_name='Variable X')
Y = df[['ID']].join(df.filter(regex='Y$')).melt(id_vars='ID', var_name='T', value_name='Variable Y')

df = pd.concat([X, Y[['Variable Y']]], axis=1).sort_values(['ID', 'T']).reset_index(drop=True)

df['T'] = df['T'].str.replace('\svariable\s[A-Za-z]', '')
```

**Output**

```
    ID      T Variable X Variable Y
0    1  Q1 09          X          Y
1    1  Q1 10          X          Y
2    1  Q2 09          X          Y
3    1  Q2 10          X          Y
4    1  Q3 09          X          Y
5    1  Q3 10          X          Y
6    1  Q4 09          X          Y
7    1  Q4 10          X          Y
8    2  Q1 09          X          Y
9    2  Q1 10          X          Y
10   2  Q2 09          X          Y
11   2  Q2 10          X          Y
12   2  Q3 09          X          Y
13   2  Q3 10          X          Y
14   2  Q4 09          X          Y
15   2  Q4 10          X          Y
16   3  Q1 09          X          Y
17   3  Q1 10          X          Y
18   3  Q2 09          X          Y
19   3  Q2 10          X          Y
20   3  Q3 09          X          Y
21   3  Q3 10          X          Y
22   3  Q4 09          X          Y
23   3  Q4 10          X          Y
24   4  Q1 09          X          Y
25   4  Q1 10          X          Y
26   4  Q2 09          X          Y
27   4  Q2 10          X          Y
28   4  Q3 09          X          Y
29   4  Q3 10          X          Y
..  ..    ...        ...        ...
42   6  Q2 09          X          Y
43   6  Q2 10          X          Y
44   6  Q3 09          X          Y
45   6  Q3 10          X          Y
46   6  Q4 09          X          Y
47   6  Q4 10          X          Y
48   7  Q1 09          X          Y
49   7  Q1 10          X          Y
50   7  Q2 09          X          Y
51   7  Q2 10          X          Y
52   7  Q3 09          X          Y
53   7  Q3 10          X          Y
54   7  Q4 09          X          Y
55   7  Q4 10          X          Y
56   8  Q1 09          X          Y
57   8  Q1 10          X          Y
58   8  Q2 09          X          Y
59   8  Q2 10          X          Y
60   8  Q3 09          X          Y
61   8  Q3 10          X          Y
62   8  Q4 09          X          Y
63   8  Q4 10          X          Y
64   9  Q1 09          X          Y
65   9  Q1 10          X          Y
66   9  Q2 09          X          Y
67   9  Q2 10          X          Y
68   9  Q3 09          X          Y
69   9  Q3 10          X          Y
70   9  Q4 09          X          Y
71   9  Q4 10          X          Y

[72 rows x 4 columns]
```

Comment: Please assume that the "X " and "Y" variables will be numbers

Comment: You can change `df.filter(regex='X$')` to whatever your data represents, `'X$'` means ends with X. So you can change the X to both variable numbers. @MadsAndersen

Comment: well the numbers will be different across all the observations, so can't just insert the numbers

Comment: Then how do you differentiate the variables from each other? You show X,Y which stand for two different variables in the columns. @MadsAndersen

Comment: No, the data is currently formatted such that the first columns contain data on the first variable, "X", across the quarters. the next columns contain data on the other variable, "Y", across the quarters. so the variables are differentiated based what the columns are named.

Comment: They are splitted on their name, not a sequence. So if you fill the correct suffix in `df.filter(regex='X$')`, the splitting of the data goes correct. @MadsAndersen

Answer (score 1):

Create `MultiIndex` by all columns with variables, so possible reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) - both `T` columns are joined together:

```
df = df.set_index('ID')
df.columns = df.columns.str.split(n=2, expand=True)
df = df.stack([0,1]).rename_axis(('ID','T','T1')).reset_index()
df['T'] = df['T'] + ' ' + df.pop('T1')
print (df.head(10))
   ID      T variable X variable Y
0   1  Q1 09          X          Y
1   1  Q1 10          X          Y
2   1  Q2 09          X          Y
3   1  Q2 10          X          Y
4   1  Q3 09          X          Y
5   1  Q3 10          X          Y
6   1  Q4 09          X          Y
7   1  Q4 10          X          Y
8   2  Q1 09          X          Y
9   2  Q1 10          X          Y
```

Or if possible create `MultiIndex` by first 5 values and another values of columns:

```
df = df.set_index('ID')
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(zip(df.columns.str[:5], df.columns.str[5:]))
df = df.stack(0).rename_axis(('ID','T')).reset_index()
```

If order is important create column with ordered [categorical](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html) and last sort values:

```
df = df.set_index('ID')
c = df.columns.str[:5]
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(zip(c, df.columns.str[5:]))
df1 = df.stack(0).rename_axis(('ID','T')).reset_index()
df1['T'] = pd.CategoricalIndex(df1['T'], ordered=True, categories=c.unique())
df1 = df1.sort_values(['ID','T'])
print (df1.head(10))
    ID      T  variable X  variable Y
0    1  Q1 09           X           Y
2    1  Q2 09           X           Y
4    1  Q3 09           X           Y
6    1  Q4 09           X           Y
1    1  Q1 10           X           Y
3    1  Q2 10           X           Y
5    1  Q3 10           X           Y
7    1  Q4 10           X           Y
8    2  Q1 09           X           Y
10   2  Q2 09           X           Y
```